# Alinhamento à direita com Styled Components

Tags: css3, react, styled-components

Preciso alinhar o conteúdo em amarelo à direita da minha barra de menus da seguinte maneira:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ao tentar, alinhar, o conteúdo fica colado aos menus:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A disposição dos meus elementos e o meu CSS estão da seguinte maneira:

```
return (
    <Container>
      <Content>
        <img src={logo} alt="FastFeet" />
        <Navigation>
          <NavLink to="/delivery">ENCOMENDAS</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/deliveryman">ENTREGADORES</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/recipient">DESTINATÁRIOS</NavLink>
          <NavLink to="/deliveryProblem">PROBLEMAS</NavLink>
        </Navigation>

        <aside>
          <Profile>
            <div>
              <strong>{profile.name}</strong>
              <button type="button" onClick={handleSignOut}>
                Sair do sistema
              </button>
            </div>
          </Profile>
        </aside>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );

import styled from 'styled-components';

export const Container = styled.div`
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 30px;
`;

export const Content = styled.div`
  height: 64px;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

  img {
    padding-right: 20px;
    max-width: 25%;
    height: auto;
  }

  nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    aside {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
  }
`;

export const Navigation = styled.div`
  padding-left: 30px;
  height: 32px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  a {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999;
    transition: color 0.5s;

    &:hover {
      color: #7159c1;
    }

    &:active {
      color: #7159c1;
    }
  }
`;

export const Profile = styled.div`
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;

  div {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    display: block;
    background: yellow;

    strong {
      display: inline;
      align-items: flex-end;
      color: #333;
    }

    button {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 2px;
      font-size: 12px;
      color: red;
      background: transparent;
      border: 0;
    }
  }
`;
```

Comment: Você já tentou `margin-left: auto` no componente `Profile`?

Answer (score 1):

Na parte:

```
export const Navigation = styled.div`
  padding-left: 30px;
  height: 32px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center; --> Alterar para "right" ou "flex-end"
```